# how to separate 1st byte from receiveddata of serial port in python

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I am interfacing raspberry pi to PIC through serial port. RPI will receive data from pic as c1,c2,c11,c14, s1,s2 etc. Is there any way to separate c and s from the received data?
I want to use

```
if receiveddata='c':
      fun1()
if receiveddata='s':
       fun2()
```

How can I do this in Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
receiveddata=ser.readline().strip()
for r in receiveddata:
     firstdata=r[0]
     seconddata=r[1]
if firstdata=='yourdata':
      fun1()
```

Answer (score 2):

```
data = ["c1", "c2", "c11", "c14", "s1", "s2"] # emulate data collected from RPI
for r in data:
  prefix = r[0]
  if prefix == 'c':
    fun1()
  elif prefix == 's':
    fun2()
```

Answer (score 1):

When you want to have special operation on first data, `next` is your friend.

For example if we emulate data collected as suggested by Arie :

```
data = ["c1", "c2", "c11", "c14", "s1", "s2"]
it = iter(data) # list does not directly accept next
first = next(it)
# deal with first item
...
for i in it: # you get here all items after first
    # other items
    ...
```

This way, you do not have to put a test inside a loop.